# Bulk delete files on Google Drive with raw XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I'm using this in chrome extension.
Simple request with file ID will delete single file

```
xhr.open('DELETE', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + ID, true);
```

If I want to delete multiple files from Google Drive, I'm looping trough ID's array and sending the same request, just multiple times.
Most of those requests succeed, but if I have more than 7-8, some of the request fail with `error code 403` (I think that stand for forbidden).
Usually if I have 12 files to delete,  two or three will fail.
(when I repeat requests, they are deleted)

Does Google Drive have some protection from throttling, and how do I delete multiple files?...
delaying with timers (eg. 100 ms) is not desirable, because I could have hundreds of files to delete, and it would take 10-30 seconds to process it

[REST Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete) doc's doesn't say anything about deleting multiple files, only single

Comment: Well, you can simply retry the request if its status code is an error...

Comment: @wOxxOm yea, I'm doing that :) ...but I don't think that's the right way... they (G-devs) must expected something like this to happen

Comment: The documentation recommends using [exponential back-off](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/handle-errors) and/or [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/batch). Also, consider migrating to API v3

Comment: @IvánNokonoko thx, I'll look into it

Comment: @IvánNokonoko example of batch request is missing from doc page :) bummer

Comment: You have one example in the [v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch)

Comment: @IvánNokonoko about v3, are you sure I can use it with raw requests (from extension)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it with `XMLHttpRequest`s without any problem

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I'm getting errors for every request if I put v3, but I guess it's not that simple. Is v2 about to be deprecated or something, when you advising switch to v3?

Comment: There are some changes between versions, you need to read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) carefully. I don't know if the v2 will be deprecated soon, but logically, if that happened, v2 would be deprecated before v3, I guess. You can try to port the v3 example to v2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sample code of batch request to delete files from Google Drive using the REST API:

```
var arrayOfFileIds;  // array of id's of the files you want to delete
//notice that currently you can only batch up to 100 requests.
var authToken;  //your OAuth2 token.
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
var boundary = "END_OF_PART";
var separation = "\n--"+boundary + "\n";
var ending = "\n--" + boundary + "--";

var requestBody = arrayOfFileIds.reduce((accum,current)=>{
           accum += separation +
           "Content-Type: application/http\n\n" +
           "DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" +
           current +
           "\nAuthorization: Bearer " + authToken;
           return accum;
         },"") + ending;

xhr.onload = ()=>{
    console.log(xhr.response);
    //handle the response
};
xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v2", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary);
xhr.send(requestBody);
```

Optionally, you can add a `content-id` header to every request (in `requestBody` above) to identify the individual responses in the batch response.

Comment: thanx for posting example. Works like a charm.