# Multipart/mixed request for google drive bulk deletion using request npm package

Tags: rest, request, google-drive-api, multipart, multipart-mixed-replace

I was trying to do bulk deletion of files from google drive using rest API. So i was framing the request for bulk deletion request i was able to achieve the deletion with the similar request framing method [Bulk delete files on Google Drive with raw XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142611/bulk-delete-files-on-google-drive-with-raw-xmlhttprequest) but i was trying to achieve this without sending the body instead of sending multipart array in the request object. I am getting error 400 with following response body

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
<H2>Error 400</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is my request object which is **failing**

```js
const _multipart = []
arrayOfFileIds.forEach((current) => {
    const obj = {
        body: 'Content-Type: application/http\n\n' +
            'DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' +
            current + '\nAuthorization: Bearer ' + authToken
    }
    _multipart.push(obj)
})

const requestOptions = {
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed'
    },
    multipart: _multipart
}
```

And below request Object is working

```js
const boundary = 'END_OF_PART'
const separation = '\n--' + boundary + '\n'
const ending = '\n--' + boundary + '--'
const requestBody = arrayOfFileIds.reduce((accum, current) => {
    accum += separation +
        'Content-Type: application/http\n\n' +
        'DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' +
        current +
        '\nAuthorization: Bearer ' + authToken
    return accum
}, '') + ending


const requestOptions = {
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=' + boundary

    },
    body: requestBody
    multipart: _multipart
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- The access token can be included in the request header.
- Put `Content-Type` of each batch request out of `body`.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
const _multipart = [];
arrayOfFileIds.forEach((current) => {
  const obj = {
    "Content-Type": "application/http",
    body: "DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + current + "\n",
  };
  _multipart.push(obj);
});

const requestOptions = {
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed",
    Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken,
  },
  multipart: _multipart,
};
```

#### Note:

- When I tested the above modified script, no error occurs. The files can be deleted. When you tested the above script, when an error occurs, please confirm the script and the access token, again.

#### Reference:

- [request](https://github.com/request/request)